# Adding components to a GameObject referenced within code

Tags: unity, c#

So in my project, I have a class called **ComponentRegistry**. The idea of this class is to store a dictionary of components and their names. For example:

```
    public Dictionary<string, MonoBehaviour> registry;
    public MonoBehaviour testComponent;

    void Start(){
        registry = new Dictionary<string, MonoBehaviour> ();
        registry.Add ("TestComponent", testComponent);
    }

    public MonoBehaviour GetScript(string name)
    {
        return registry[name];
    }
```

Then in a separate class, I will access this dictionary using a string in order to retrieve the associated component, subsequently adding the associated component to the gameObject.

```
    foreach (string comp in blockInfo.components) { 

    //For each of the components that need to be added

        gameObject.AddComponent(ScriptMaster.compReg.GetScript(comp)); 

        //I know this is incorrect, but the idea is there
}
```

Just for understanding, **compReg** is an instance of the **ComponentRegister** class stored as a static variable within my **ScriptMaster** class.

But no matter what I try, I have not been able to get this to work. I have switched endlessly between different formatting of adding components to gameObjects, alternating between using Components and MonoBehaviours, adding by type.

Thank you for any insight.

Comment: "I have not been able to get this to work" - how would you like it to work? What exactly didnt work while using described approaches? And most importantly, what are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: The end goal is to be able to add components to a gameObject that are stored in a dictionary in a script. No fomat of AddComponent I can make to work with what I have in place, the format essentially being "AddComponent(ComponentFromScript)" I believe that I am not passing/using the right variable type for storing a constructor. The proposed solution is that I can dynamically add scripts based on the type of object it is.

Comment: Do you want to add specific script (= *instance*) or script of  specific *type* or perhaps *copy* of specific instance? There are huge differences between those and you do not specify what exactly you are after.

Comment: Yes, so I want an equivalent of this: AddComponent<RigidBody>(), but instead of RigidBody, I pass a type stored in a dictionary, so I would assume I would be looking for an instance of that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to create new instance of said script instead of passing reference to an existing instance. In order to do  that, you can either implement the [Factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), or one of the `IConeable` variations/semantics - which would also allow you to have several "default" settings of one script.
Alternatively, if you need *just* "get an instance by type name" semantics, you can use the [Activator.CreateInstance()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d133hta4.aspx):

```
//you should be able to get the correct name by typeof(T).FullName 
// or instance.GetType().FullName 
foreach (string compTypeName in blockInfo.components)
  gameObject.AddComponent(Activator.CreateInstance(null, compTypeName ).Unwrap());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience, you have saved me a whole load of work!